Animated cartoon about a group of friends who possess unique powers relating to nature
The plot of the animated series centers around a group of six or seven friends, each possessing unique powers related to the elements of nature.
The main character, who has gray hair and an unusual name consisting of two or three letters, has lost his parents, and his story immerses viewers in the darker moments of his past.
Among his friends is a boy with red hair, who embodies the element of fire and often displays a rebellious attitude. In critical moments, each friend is aided by dragon spirits that appear to assist them in their battles against dark forces.
In one episode, they find themselves in a building with several rooms, where each confronts their own fears and dreams, interacting with a tall illusionary woman. While there is one female character, the primary focus is on friendship and teamwork among the friends, with the atmosphere of the series varying from light to dark.
I watched this animated series in 2015-2016.

Legend of the Dragon? Ang is the hero, elemental powers, dragons. Not a terribly good match to the other stuff about his group of friends, nor does he have grey hair.

Gormiti? - Elemental powers, small group of friends, one of whom has grey hair. All the characters had short (four-letter) names.

Kaijudo: Rise of the Duel Masters? Ray is the main character, element-themed powers, also dragons. Lead character has blue/grey hair depending on the lighting.

Could this be Di-Gata Defenders or Yo-kai Watch Shadowside?

Perhaps a rerun of Captain Planet and the Planeteers? It doesn't check all boxes, but memory is a capricious thing :)

@Joachim My head was singing Captain Planet Title Tract until the dragon came lol

Was it a western series or japanese anime? Anything particular about the style of the animation / characters?
